# Hide progress of Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, progress, powershell-3.0

How can I hide the progress display of `Invoke-WebRequest`? I do a lot of successive requests and have my own `Write-Progress` display that I use, so I don't need the built-in one popping up underneath it every time.

I use the mshtml results (the IE COM object) that are created from the result of `Invoke-WebRequest` automatically, so I can't switch to a `WebClient` or something like that, unless someone provides instructions on how to get an mshtml object from a WebClient request.

Comment: Note that performance is order of magnitudes better when hiding progressbar. I was waiting for few minutes until I canceled <300MB download. When turned off progress bar, it completed within few seconds. Related: [Progress bar can significantly impact cmdlet performance](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2138)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use the $progressPreference variable.  It should have a value of 'Continue' by default unless you've edited it elsewhere, which tells Powershell to display the progress bar. Since you mentioned that you have your own custom progress displays, I would reset it immediately after the cmdlet is executed.  For example:

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'    # Subsequent calls do not display UI.
Invoke-WebRequest ...
$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'            # Subsequent calls do display UI.
Write-Progress ...
```

More info on preference variables at [about_preference_variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx).  Here's the entry for $ProgressPreference:

```
$ProgressPreference
-------------------
Determines how Windows PowerShell responds to progress updates 
        generated by a script, cmdlet or provider, such as the progress bars
        generated by the Write-Progress cmdlet. The Write-Progress cmdlet 
        creates progress bars that depict the status of a command.

        Valid values:
          Stop:               Does not display the progress bar. Instead,
                                it displays an error message and stops executing.

          Inquire:            Does not display the progress bar. Prompts
                                for permission to continue. If you reply
                                with Y or A, it displays the progress bar.

          Continue:           Displays the progress bar and continues with
          (Default)             execution.

          SilentlyContinue:   Executes the command, but does not display
                                the progress bar.
```

Comment: In case anyone else has issues with this... you may need to explicitly specify `$global:progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'` if calling in to other script blocks.

Comment: Using `$oldProgressPreference = $progressPreference; $progressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';` and later `$progressPreference = $oldProgressPreference` will in addition retain the previous setting which can improve consistency when linking scripts.

Comment: @ChrisBaxter thanks! Without the `$global` bit it was working fine for me when I had the commands written out in my CI config directly, but it stopped working once I moved it into a powershell script. Setting the global variable fixed it right up!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a **reusable function** to temporarily hide the progress of any *script block* and automatically restore the progress preference when the script block ends, **even if an exception** (script-terminating error) is thrown by the script block.

```sh
# Create an in-memory module so $ScriptBlock doesn't run in new scope
$null = New-Module {
    function Invoke-WithoutProgress {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory)] [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
        )

        # Save current progress preference and hide the progress
        $prevProgressPreference = $global:ProgressPreference
        $global:ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

        try {
            # Run the script block in the scope of the caller of this module function
            . $ScriptBlock
        }
        finally {
            # Restore the original behavior
            $global:ProgressPreference = $prevProgressPreference
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
Invoke-WithoutProgress {
    # Here $ProgressPreference is set to 'SilentlyContinue'
    Invoke-WebRequest ...
}

# Now $ProgressPreference is restored
Write-Progress ...
```

**Notes:**

- The `New-Module` call is there so the script block passed to `Invoke-WithoutProgress` **doesn't run in a new scope** (allowing it to directly modify surrounding variables, similar to `ForEach-Object`'s script block). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885218/7571258) for more information.

Comment: Just wondering, doesn't this technically also swallow exceptions, which may be undesired? I like the approach (have done similar stuff with lambdas in C++ and Python), but swallowing exceptions as a side effect should probably be noted. Thanks for showing the technique, though.

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, it doesn't swallow exceptions as there is no `catch` block in the function. The `finally` block just makes sure that the `$ProgressPreference` variable is restored in any case, but exceptions still bubble up the call stack, after the `finally` block has been run.

Answer (score 4):

[PowerShell 7.4 has been released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-74?view=powershell-7.3#breaking-changes) and it has added `-ProgressAction` as a common parameter to all the cmdlets. This means you can use `-ProgressAction SilentlyContinue` for `Invoke-WebRequest` and easily hide its progress.

Comment: This is unfortunately currently a bit broken, as per this GitHub issue: [The -ProgressAction parameter doesn't work (PowerShell 7.4.1 only)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21074)