# Suppress information of Test-NetConnection

Tags: powershell

How can I supress the detailed information from `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost` for a PowerShell session?

`Test-NetConnection` writes quite a bit of information to the console which is displayed in the top of the console, overwriting the progress bar.

[image]

<strike>The output can be suppressed by setting the `-InformationLevel` to `Quiet` like so</strike>
It looked like the output could be supressed like with the `-InformationLevel` parameter, however it turns out that even with `-InformationLevel` to `Quiet` the information in the top of the console is shown.

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -InformationLevel Quiet
```

I would like to set the `InformationLevel` just once for the whole script, like you would [suppress the progress bar when using `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770723/hide-progress-of-invoke-webrequest).

```
$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'    # Subsequent calls do not display UI.
Invoke-WebRequest ...
$progressPreference = 'Continue'            # Subsequent calls do display UI.
```

To my knowledge there is no similar `$InformationLevelPreference` Test-NetConnection will listen to.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to Ansgar's proposed solution would be to use the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values):

```
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection localhost

ComputerName           : localhost
RemoteAddress          : ::1
InterfaceAlias         : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress          : ::1
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms

PS C:\> $PSDefaultParameterValues['Test-NetConnection:InformationLevel'] = 'Quiet'
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection localhost
True
```

Entries in `$PSDefaultParameterValues` dictionary have keys in the form of `CommandName:ParameterName`, and then the value is the parameter argument value you want to supply by default. You can incorporate wildcards as part of the `CommandName` part if necessary

---

The reason that you might have seen the progress bar go away when switching to `-InformationLevel:Quiet` is that issuing a single ICMP request to a loopback interface and returning a single boolean value happens so fast that the host application never has a chance to actually pick up the progress stream state change and display the progress overlay before returning to the prompt.

If you want to suppress the progress bar at the top during execution (regardless of how long the command is running), use the `$ProgressPreference` variable:

```
PS C:\> $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
PS C:\> Test-NetConnection localhost
```

Comment: Nice one. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: I did not know about `$PSDefaultParameterValues` either. I did find strange behaviour. Your solution works fine for `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost`, but it it does not work with `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 80`!

Comment: @JanH Interesting - it works just fine here, what output are you getting other than `$true/$false`?

Comment: Actually, withe the `-Port` parameter it works as expected. Using `PSDefaultParameterValues` renders the same behavior as using `Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 80 -InformationLevel Quiet`

Comment: In the question I stated that `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -InformationLevel Quiet` suppresses the information shown on top of the window, but it does not. I think I have to rephrase the question.

Comment: @JanH Sounds like you're trying to supress progress information being displayed by the host. There's a preference variable for that :-) I've updated the answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the suggestion! Somehow with `Test-NetConnection` the `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue` only works if you set it in the console itself. When setting the progresspreference in a script it does not work.

Comment: @JanH Try setting `$global:ProgressPreference`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers brilliant! that totally solves my problem. And yeah, I should read up on PowerShell variable scopes again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `Test-NetConnection` in a function and use a global variable for your preference.

```
$NetConnectionVerbosity = 'Quiet'

function Test-CustomNetConnection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ComputerName = 'localhost',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$InformationLevel = $script:NetConnectionVerbosity
    )

    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $ComputerName -InformationLevel $InformationLevel
}

Test-CustomNetConnection
```

You could supersede `Test-NetConnection` with a custom function and an alias:

```
$NetConnectionVerbosity = 'Quiet'

function Test-CustomNetConnection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ComputerName = 'localhost',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$InformationLevel = $script:NetConnectionVerbosity
    )

    $f = Get-Command -Name 'Test-NetConnection' -CommandType Function
    & $f -ComputerName $ComputerName -InformationLevel $InformationLevel
}

New-Alias -Name 'Test-NetConnection' -Value 'Test-CustomNetConnection'

Test-NetConnection
```

The above defines a custom function that gets and invokes the original `Test-NetConnection` function, then defines an alias `Test-NetConnection` for the custom function. Since aliases take [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-3.0) over functions invocations of `Test-NetConnection` calls will now invoke `Test-CustomNetConnection`, which in turn invokes the original `Test-NetConnection` with the desired parameters.

Creating a [proxy function](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/) might also be an option.

Comment: Good idea. In my case there is a 3rd party installation script which uses `Test-NetConnection`. I cannot change that script so I am looking for a solution where I can change the behavior of `Test-NetConnection` in another way. I do not want to supress the output of the installation script completely either because it has some valuable information.