# Node.js / Powershell - Suppress progress output

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I'm automating a process for which I'm executing `powershell` commands from `node.js` using the `node-cmd` package. to get few file I/O operations done. However I'm unable to suppress the output for which I've referred other SO posts and found nothing relevant to my issue.

**EDIT:**  Here is the `powershell` command which I'm using to generate the zip file.

```
powershell Compress-Archive -Force -Path WebContent\* -DestinationPath portal
```

Can someone guide me how I can hide get this done?

[image: Compress-Archive progress screenshot]

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen, Thanks for pointing me to that link, Do we have any detailed examples regarding `silentlyContinue` and `continue`?

Comment: This one is very close to my issue => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214143/suppress-information-of-test-netconnection

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to detail. With `SilentlyContinue`, the host application simply ignores progress events raised without showing the progress bar

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen, Shall I go ahead and delete this post since it is a duplicate?