# How does Measure-Command invoke ScriptBlock in parent scope?

Tags: powershell, scope

In the example below after `Measure-Command` variable `x` is updated, but in example with my own version of command `x` remains the same.

```
$x = 0
Measure-Command -Expression { $x++ } | Out-Null
$x # outputs 1

function Measure-Command2
{
    param([ScriptBlock]$Expression)
    . $Expression
}
$x = 0
Measure-Command2 -Expression { $x++ }
$x # outputs 0
```

Can I use the same magic in my own functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most user-friendly solution is to define your function in a *dynamic module*, using 
[`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module):

```
$null = New-Module {
  function Measure-Command2 {
    param([ScriptBlock]$Expression)
    . $Expression
  }
}

$x = 0
Measure-Command2 -Expression { $x++ }
$x # outputs *1* now, as desired.
```

Note:

- Modules run in their own scope domain aka session state that is separate from the caller's. Thus, unlike with non-module functions, *no* child scope of the caller's scope is created on invocation.
- The script block passed as an argument, due to having been created as a literal (`{ ... }`) in the caller's scope, executes *there*, not in the function's.

---

Without a module, you'd need to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the invocation of `Measure-Command2` *itself*, given that functions and scripts run in a *child scope* by default:

```
function Measure-Command2 {
  param([ScriptBlock]$Expression)
  . $Expression
}
$x = 0
# Note the dot-sourcing
. Measure-Command2 -Expression { $x++ }
$x # outputs *1* now, as desired.
```