# Powershell IWR showing bytes read in output how can I suppress these messages?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I have a simple script to test the blocking of palo test sites. How to suppress the bytes read message and have a clean output?

```
$palotestsites = @("http://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/test-web-based-email",
    "http://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/test-cryptocurrency",
    "http://urlfiltering.paloaltonetworks.com/test-grayware")
foreach ($t in $palotestsites)
{
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest $t -MaximumRedirection 1
        Write-Host "  "  $response.statuscode " " $t -ForegroundColor Green
        
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "  " $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__ " " $t -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'    # Subsequent calls do not display UI.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770794